# Parsing a uniprot flat file

Tags: python, text-parsing

Can anybody please let me know or help with parsing a uniprot flat file and access the information in the annotation (FT) line and produce an output file in python script. FT line is the on in a general uniprot flat file describing the nature of the proteins. Script written to this must produce an output file with the information in this line.

Comment: I suggest you ask this on http://biostar.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at biopython: http://biopython.org

In particular, their SeqIO module: http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO